# Send_file open file in browse instead of download it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please tell me how this works, because I don't understand... Here is my simple code:

Route:

```
 get 'download' =>'pages#download'
```

My action:

```
def download
  send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/robots.zip", :type=>"application/zip"
```

And download link:

```
<%= link_to "download", download_path %>
```

So, when i'm clicking on the link I get this:

[Image http://joxi.ru/GrqvQ3xHlbaYmz.jpg](http://joxi.ru/GrqvQ3xHlbaYmz.jpg)

It seems like the browser is trying to show zip file content... But when I open the action from my browser (or refresh page) it's working fine.

Why doesn't it work when I click on the link generated by `link_to`?

Comment: Which browser you used ? It looks like a problem of configuration browser

Comment: set the option `disposition: 'attachment'` in the `send_file` method. UPDATE: disregard this since `attachment` is the default.

Comment: in all browsers

Answer (score 4):

Adding `disposition: "inline"` instead of `disposition: "attachment"` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Send_file open file in browse instead of download it

Try with this

```
def download
  send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/robots.zip", :type=>"application/zip",:disposition=> "attachment; filename=robots.zip")
end
```

and

```
<%= link_to "download", download_path ,target: '_self' ,  data-turbolinks="false" %>
```