# send_file: PDF seems corrupted (?) and doesn't trigger download, opens in broswer instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

This is my `routes.rb`

```
resources :welcome do
  get :download, :on => :collection
end
```

I have tried 2 variations in my `controller`

First

```
def download
  send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/assets/resources/testing.pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment")
end
```

Second

```
def download
  send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/assets/resources/#{params[:file_name]}", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment")
end
```

This is my `view` and i have tried 2 different `link_to` according to the controller action.

First

```
<%= link_to 'Test Paper', action: :download %>
```

Second

```
<%= link_to 'Test Paper', action: :download, file_name: 'testing.pdf' %>
```

Neither of them are working and i don't know why. I actually saw a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773638/send-file-open-file-in-browse-instead-of-download-it), but unfortunately there are no answers there.

The download doesn't trigger, it just opens the PDF in the browser, and it renders in a "corrupted" format. What am i missing?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: You file is in the public folder and therefore can be served without Rails. Why don't you just redirect the user to `/assets/resources/testing.pdf`?

Comment: If i redirect them there are they able to download the pdf? Might be a silly question i know...

Comment: I wonder what will happen if the users passes the string `'../../../config/database.yml'` via `params[:file_name]` to the server?

Comment: When you redirect them they will download the file, why do you think they wouldn't?

Comment: so its not wise to allow users to download through params[:file_name] ? what would be a more advisable solution if i have multiple pdf documents for users to download?

Comment: how would they pass in the string if my downloads method is pointing to /public/assets/resources though?

Comment: by adding `?file_name=...` to the URL.

Comment: but doesn't the download method in the controller restrict it to files found in assets/resources ?

Comment: No, it will send any file as longs as Rails is allowed to read it. Since the underlying OS will resolve relative paths an attacker will be able to return the content of all your files (when he had learned how to build the relative part). Redirecting seems to be a better idea, because the web server will only return file in the `public` folder or a 404 if not found.

Comment: meaning to say i should be redirecting users to /assets/resources/testing.pdf? and if i have another pdf then i redirect them to /assets/resources/testing2.pdf ?

Comment: If the files are named that way: Yes. Or you might build links directly to that files, if that is possible.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Yes i am. Is it the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes it is. Let me compose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
def download
  file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/assets/resources/#{params[:file_name]}")
   send_data file.read, :filename => params[:file_name], :type => 'application/pdf', :x_sendfile => true
end
```

Comment: doesn't work. its still opening in the browser, not triggering the download, and showing a "corrupted" pdf page.

Comment: still receiving the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're using turbolinks, you need to add `data: {turbolinks: 'false'}` to attributes of the link.

`<%= link_to 'Test Paper', action: :download, data: {turbolinks: 'false'} %>`

This is for Turbolinks 5. For previous versions, try `'data-no-turbolink': true`

Comment: hi sorry i only managed to try the code now. unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: What version of Turbolinks are you using?

Comment: Its okay! Thanks for trying to help. I have decided to render the asset instead. Cheers!